# Check whether status bar is hidden or visible

Tags: iphone, statusbar

I want to check condition for statusbar. How can i check condition if status bar is visible or not .

please anyone guide me to do this..

Thank you all

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Check if status bar is hidden:

**Objective C**:

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].isStatusBarHidden) {
    // do stuff here...
}
```

**Swift**:

```
if UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden {
    // do stuff here...
}
```

Hide status bar:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: You have an extra left bracket just before UIApplication. The correct code is if ( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden == YES){
//do stuff
}

Comment: In fact [UIApplication sharedApplication].isStatusBarHidden

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
if UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden {
    // Do something
}
```

To hide the status bar (`setStatusBarHidden` is deprecated in iOS 9)
override in your `ViewController`:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current state by using the `statusBarHidden` property of `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`

You can set the current state using `– setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:`

See the docs for [more awesome stuff](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIStatusBarStyleDefault).

HTH

Answer (score -1):

U can Also check this in xib of interface builder in view attributes u can see four options for it gray/ black/ translucent/ unspecified..